# Using Java objects as request parameters breaks down to primitives in swagger ui springfox

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I have the following controller code

```
@GetMapping("/users")
public ResponseEntity<UserDto> getUsers(Filter filter) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.findUsers(filter));
}
```

Filter.java:

```
public class Filter {
    private Integer page;

    private Integer size;

    // Contains 2 fields: "propertyName" and "order"
    private Sort sort;

    ... getters and setters
}
```

The URL is following: `/users?page=1&size=10&sort=+firstName`. So I have a custom converter from `String` to `Sort` and it works perfectly.

However, the generated swagger documentation is incorrect:

```
"parameters":[  
           {  
              "name":"sort.propertyName",
              "in":"query",
              "required":false,
              "type":"string"
           },
           {  
              "name":"sort.order",
              "in":"query",
              "required":false,
              "type":"string",
              "enum":[  
                 "+",
                 "-"
              ]
           },
           {  
              "name":"page",
              "in":"query",
              "required":false,
              "type":"integer",
              "format":"int32"
           },
           {  
              "name":"size",
              "in":"query",
              "required":false,
              "type":"integer",
              "format":"int32"
           }
]
```

As you can see, it has broken down the `Sort` field of `Filter` and has generated 2 parameters: `sort.propertyName` and `sort.order`. Instead, I want to have one parameter `sort` with type `string`.

Is there any way to achieve that? I have tried annotating the `sort` field with `@ApiParam(name = "sort", value = "Sort", type = "string")`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You can create an alternate type rule to treat `Sort` as a `String`

Comment: Thanks, @DilipKrishnan, that worked! Can you please add your comment as an answer, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an alternate type rule that treats `Sort` as a `String`

```
import static springfox.documentation.schema.AlternateTypeRules.*;
...
// Configure your docket bean
    new Docket(...)
         ...
         .alternateTypeRules(newRule(Sort.class, String.class)
         ...
```